# Prove, using only the definition of $O()$, that $2^{\sqrt{x}}$ is not $O(x^{10})$

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

Prove, using only the definition of $O()$, that $2^{\sqrt{x}}$ is not $O(x^{10})$.

I have been doing a few exercises on Big O and this is the first time I have encountered the variable in the exponent.  I was wondering how to disprove this function.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: For every $c$, find $x_0$ so that $2^{\sqrt{x}} > cx^{10}$ for all $x \geq x_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try converting both functions to the form $e^{f'(x)}$.

Comment: Or, since $\log_2$ is an increasing function, take $\log_2$ of both sides and compare the results.

Comment: @RickDecker Merely comparing the results isn't enough: $x^2 \notin O(x)$, but $\log(x^2) \in O(\log(x))$. You can take the logs on both sides (and that's what FrankW is suggesting with different wording), but you still need to plug that into the definition of $O$.

Comment: @Gilles. Of course. My point was that it's then clearer that one can't find a $c$ for which $\sqrt{x} \le c\cdot10\cdot\log_2x$.

Answer (score 0):

$O(x^{10})$ is $O(x^k)$ for some constant $k$ (polynomial complexity) whereas $O(2^{\sqrt{x}})=O(2^{x^k})$ is subexponential by definition.

Using De l'Hôpital's rule, you can find the following:

$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \displaystyle\frac{x^{10}}{2^{\sqrt{x}}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\frac{\delta x^{10}}{\delta x}}{\frac{\delta 2^{\sqrt{x}}}{\delta x}}=0
$

which shows that the denominator grows faster than the numerator. You can actually differentiate the fraction until you get a constant numerator while the denominator will always stay a function of $x$.